Understanding tungsten's temperature-dependent work function
I found little to no information about tungsten's temperature-dependent work function on literature.
However, the information I found describes a positive angular coefficient for the equation:
$$\omega=\omega_0+\alpha T$$
Which seems to mean that tungsten's work function increases with temperature.
This seems extremely counter-intuitive to me. Is that right? Am I misinterpreting something?
[1] https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.58.623

Note that the linked abstract (published in 1940) explicitly says the work function increases with temperature, with $\alpha≈6.3×10^{-5}$ volts per kelvin. I don't know the mechanism. Is it discussed in the paper?

I think the mechanism is somewhat described by what @Sidd mentioned below. This helps me trust my understanding of the article. Thanks for the help :)

On page 632, the paper mentions "Considering the effect of thermal expansion on the density of tungsten, which enters into the computation, $W_i$ may be computed to decrease with increase of temperature by about $10^{-4}$ volt per degree."
The paper also mentions that "... work function is expressed in the form, $W_a - W_i$, where $W_a$ is the amount of work which an electron at rest must do to escape from the surface and $W_i$ is the Fermi "characteristic energy" of the electrons in the metal, the above experimental evidence implies that the temperature effect in $W_i$ predominates over that in $W_a$.

Understood, this makes sense. Thanks so much for the help :)
